# In android studio How I import a text file and how I tokenize this file to save it in sqlite3 database?

Tags: android, sqlite

How I import a text file in android studio and then how I tokenize it for saving it in sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick references for ya, hope it helps.

Files read/write: http://www.androidinterview.com/android-internal-storage-read-and-write-text-file-example/

SQLite Tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html